# Difference between dom.byId() vs dojo.byId()?

Tags: dojo

I'm a beginner to dojo toolkit. And I know that `dojo.byId()` function is similar to JavaScript's `document.getElementById()` but I don't understand what's the use of `dom.byId()`.

Can someone explain me what are the differences between dom.byId() and dojo.byId()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dojo syntax is pre AMD using the global dojo object. The dom syntax is when you load the dojo/dom module with the new AMD structure.

**Edit**

I suppose I should add an example.

```
// Pre-AMD (<1.7)
dojo.ready(function(){
    var elm = dojo.byId('myElement'); // id="myElement"
})
// Dojo using AMD (1.7+)
require(['dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'], function(dom){
    var elm = dom.byId('myElement');
})
```

Dojo and AMD is tricky to get used to, at least it was for me.

More on AMD from [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)